# Questions about scalable IoT cluster design

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue, iot

My English is not good, the following is basically a machine translation, please understand.

I'm recently researching IoT, and I want to design a scalable IoT cluster to be deployed in Kubernetes, I'm recently researching IoT and want to design a scalable IoT cluster to be deployed in Kubernetes, but I'm having problems designing device connectivity services.

I've come up with a few options myself so far：

1. Using stateless service, all Pods consume the same Kafka queue, they are the same Kafka Group, Pods communicate with each other via HTTP/RPC, then the connection information of the device needs to be stored in third-party middleware, such as database, redis.
2. Using stateful services, each Pod is a separate Kafka Group, and each Pod has a separate Kafka Topic; they also consume the same source data Kafka Topic at the same time, and when the Pod consumes the data, it determines whether the device is connected to itself, and if not, it takes out the connection information from redis and sends the data to another Pod's Kafka Topic inside.
3. Also using stateful services, each Pod is a separate Kafka Group and there is a separate Kafka Topic for each Pod; but before them, there is a service called Router that takes messages out of the source data Kafka Topic and then determines which Pod each device is connected to and sends the data to the specified Kafka Topic.
4. Stateful or stateless is possible, each device corresponds to a Kafka Group and a Kafka Topic, and the data is sent to the specified Topic through the Router's service.
5. Stateful or stateless can be used, this time using RabbitMQ, each device is a client, and each device is a Queue, through the Router's service to send data to the specified Queue.

There are a few questions：

1. Because the use of Kafka for data interaction, then it will lead to a reduction in the concurrency of each Pod, if there are 100 data in the Topic, each is a different device, theoretically the best case is the 100 data concurrently sent to the 100 devices, but because of Kafka, this is difficult to achieve, it seems to add only partition.
2. It seems that too much Kakfa Topic will have a performance impact if the 4 solution is used.
3. It seems that too many RabbitMQ Queues and clients will also have a performance impact if the 5 solution is used.
4. At the moment I am in contact with more is kafka and RabbitMQ, I do not know if there is a better message queue.